# Change field type in Odata OrderBy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, odatacontroller

I have `OdataService` with CustDetails table (I am using `Entity Framework`). In the table I have column PostalCode of string type. When I sort the data it working fine. It sort the data by considering it as string type. But my requirement is, in my PostalCode all values are integer value only , so I need to sort the data by considering it as integer type. Is it possible to change the field data type while sorting ?

Actual sorted Result:

```
100,
1100,
12,
2,
200
```

But My expected result is

```
2,
12,
100,
200,
1100
```

Please help me to overcome this. **Note**: I am not able to change the data type in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OData doesn't support conversion of primitive types in the query. See [Odata Query String Options](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/#QueryStringOptions)

You could, however, write a service operation to handle this for you (assuming your query provider supports this).

Comment: thanks for your answer :). I will try your suggestion.